Grammatical issues and failures: help is needed
I realize that I am quite weak in English and I frequently do mistakes in grammatical things in English during my examination. Can you guys suggest me some good books to overcome this weakness over English?

Please ask this question on Language Learning, not here. :) [make mistakes NOT do mistakes; suggest x to me, not suggest me] Try the BBC English language sites. They're very good.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about English but learning English.
